# On which side of vector the point is

Tags: euclidean-geometry, vector-analysis

I have a vector A and a point P. My problem is how to find out if point is on the left or right side of vector looking from the point of origin of a vector in direction of it.

Comment: Do you know of any ways to measure the angle between the vector $A$ and the vector going from the origin to $P$?

Comment: @Jesse yes but only absolute value of it.

Comment: Do you know the formula $a \cdot b = |a||b|\cos \theta$ (where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors)? In case the answer is yes, how can you use this formula to answer your question?

Comment: @Fredrik Yes, but in my case this formula is not helpful. Note that $cos( \theta ) = cos(0 - \theta )$.

Comment: One way is to perform a rotation $\phi$ so that $\phi(A)$ lies on the x-axis and then inspect the sign of the y-coordinate of $\phi(P)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44096/detecting-whether-directed-cycle-is-clockwise-or-counterclockwise/44098#44098) on MO should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B$ be the vector from the end point of $A$ to $P$, then observe the sign of the coefficient of $A \wedge B$ in a chosen basis. The exact sign is up to $O(2)/SO(2)$, but you only need to distinguish between the two cases, so it's ok :)

UPD: Now that I think about it, letting $B$ be the vector from the starting point of $A$ to $P$ is even neater.